# How to sort numbers in Javascript and find the position of an element in it by taking user inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a form which takes in numbers from the user. I want to sort these numbers and show the output. Also after sorting I want the user to enter a number present in the array and show the position of the element in the sorted array.

But I am getting stuck at the sorting stage itself.

Here is the code that I am trying:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="f">
    <pre>
        Enter number 1: <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        Enter number 2: <input type="text" name="second" id="second">
        Enter number 3: <input type="text" name="third" id="third">
        Enter number 4: <input type="text" name="fourth" id="fourth">
        Enter number 5: <input type="text" name="fifth" id="fifth">
        Enter number 6: <input type="text" name="sixth" id="sixth">
        Enter number 7: <input type="text" name="seventh" id="seventh">
        Enter number 8: <input type="text" name="eighth" id="eighth">
        Enter number 9: <input type="text" name="ninth" id="ninth">
        Enter number 10: <input type="text" name="tenth" id="tenth">
    </pre>
    <br>
    <button onclick="sortfunction()">Click to sort</button>
    <br><br>
    Sorted numbers: <input type="text" name="sorted">
</form>

<script>
    function sortfunction()
    {
        var num=new Array();
        num[0]=document.getElementById("first");
        num[1]=document.getElementById("second");
        num[2]=document.getElementById("third");
        num[3]=document.getElementById("fourth");
        num[4]=document.getElementById("fifth");
        num[5]=document.getElementById("sixth");
        num[6]=document.getElementById("seventh");
        num[7]=document.getElementById("eighth");
        num[8]=document.getElementById("ninth");
        num[9]=document.getElementById("tenth");
        num.sort();
        document.f.sorted.value=num;
    }
</script>
```

When I am clicking on click to sort, the output box shows 
`[object HTML InputElement],[object HTML InputElement],...`

Where am I going wrong? Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to get the value of each element. Try this: `num[0] = document.getElementById('first').value`. Do that for all of the elements.

Comment: @JosanIracheta Right! That was silly of me to overlook! But after doing that, the result is appearing for a second and going away, and even the text boxes are getting empty.

Comment: That's because you are submitting the form. You need to stop the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value of input html element use selector.value example `document.getElementById("first").value`.

Also sort function need to get some compare function as by default it will convert number into string and then sort. See  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more
Compare function

```
(a,b)=>Number(a)>=Number(b)?1:-1
```

Here is the code which solve your problem

```
    <form name="f">
    <pre>
        Enter number 1: <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        Enter number 2: <input type="text" name="second" id="second">
        Enter number 3: <input type="text" name="third" id="third">
        Enter number 4: <input type="text" name="fourth" id="fourth">
        Enter number 5: <input type="text" name="fifth" id="fifth">
        Enter number 6: <input type="text" name="sixth" id="sixth">
        Enter number 7: <input type="text" name="seventh" id="seventh">
        Enter number 8: <input type="text" name="eighth" id="eighth">
        Enter number 9: <input type="text" name="ninth" id="ninth">
        Enter number 10: <input type="text" name="tenth" id="tenth">
    </pre>
    <br>
    <button onclick="sortfunction()">Click to sort</button>
    <br><br>
    Sorted numbers: <input type="text" name="sorted">
</form>
<script>


    function sortfunction(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var num=new Array();
    num[0]=document.getElementById("first").value;
    num[1]=document.getElementById("second").value;
    num[2]=document.getElementById("third").value;
    num[3]=document.getElementById("fourth").value;
    num[4]=document.getElementById("fifth").value;
    num[5]=document.getElementById("sixth").value;
    num[6]=document.getElementById("seventh").value;
    num[7]=document.getElementById("eighth").value;
    num[8]=document.getElementById("ninth").value;
    num[9]=document.getElementById("tenth").value;
    num.sort((a,b)=>Number(a)>=Number(b)?1:-1)
    document.f.sorted.value=num;
        }
    </script>
```

See working example at [codepen](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/QOaQge)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("first");
```

returns the element `input` here and that is a `object HTML InputElement` type. One more thing I would like to add,
instead of manually collecting all the input of text type by id you can collect it in a loop that will save your time and also you don't have to worry about number of inputs.
Ex:

```
 <script>
        var num = new Array();
        var textInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i=0; i<textInputs.length; i++)
        {
            if(textInputs[i].getAttribute('type')=='text')
            {
                num.push(textInputs[i].value);
            }
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: I like what you said about the no limits to the input. Could you show a sample form for this? With the sorting result showing?

Comment: Hello see this [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/skhalequ/apLL6Luy/4/) . The code is running fine in my system. Unfortunately I am new in fiddle so the output is not showing there properly. You can try this in your system.

Comment: Check my sort function specially in the fiddle.